# Group pandas dataframe and calculate mean for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to group a pandas dataframe by a column and then also calculate the mean for multiple columns.
In the sample below I would like to group by the 'category' column and then calculate the mean for the 'score' and 'priority' columns. All three columns should be in the resulting dataframe.

I am able to group and calculate the mean for the first column but I don't know how to add the second column. Below my attempt.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['A', 2, 1], ['A', 4, 2], ['B', 5, 3], ['B', 2, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['category', 'score', 'priority'])
print(df)

#  This fails:
results_df = df.groupby('category')['score'].agg(['mean',])['priority'].agg(['mean',])
print(results_df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
df.groupby("category", as_index=False).mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first three lines correctly print out the result

```
  category  score  priority
0        A      2         1
1        A      4         2
2        B      5         3
3        B      2         3
```

Now add this line:

```
df.groupby("category").mean(numeric_only=True)
```

and you will see:

```
          score  priority
category                 
A           3.0       1.5
B           3.5       3.0
```

which is probably what you're looking for. Running `mean(numeric_only=True)` on a DataFrame calculates means for all numeric columns. (You can leave it out right now, but you'll get a deprecated-feature message.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).